# How to select correct ojdbc version accourding to Oracle FAQ?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, ojdbc

I know there is some questions about this but none of these are not telling how to choose. So I have oracle database version 19c and jdk 17 microservice. When I look [Oracle FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html) I have 3 options to use.

[image: JDBC and RDBMS interoperability matrix]

Also as I told, I have jdk 17. That means I can use ojdbc10 or ojdbc8.

[image: Oracle JDBC releases Vs JDK]

I let my spring boot parent to choose by not give version as in pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.nls</groupId>
    <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and when I `mvn install` I can see it installs `jdbc 21.9.0.0`. As far as I can tell, it will work with database 19.x when I look first chart. But I'm not sure about it's compatible with JDK17. Second chart tells ojdbc8 with database 19.x is fully compatible with JDK17 but how is it? Shouldn't this chart be in the form jdbc version x jdbc jar. What does jdk have to do with database version?

Comment: Use the highest version compatible with your database (which is the 23.3 driver), and the ojdbcxx version equal to or lower to your Java version (ojdbc11 in the case of 23.3). Also, I have voted to close as opinion-based, because other people will gladly argue that you should use the version matching your database version.

Comment: I actually didn't ask best one for me to use. I only asked how to check which versions I can use according to Oracle official documents. It just "teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime" thing

Comment: The first image clearly shows that you can use 23.3 with a 19.x database. It is unclear to me why you're even asking the question then. And we're not Oracle customer support, we're not here to explain to you what Oracle meant with their documentation.

Comment: First table shows that, you are right but I need to know if related jar certified for jdk 17 which second table trying to show me. But table describes the relationship through oracle database version which confuses me since I expect JDBC driver version for to choose which JDK compatible with which one. There are Oracle workers do answers some topics here like Jean, please be kind. You can easily ignore topic if you are not interested to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library name is "ojdbc8" and that indicates that it was compiled with Java 8 and therefore implements the JDBC 4.2 spec. The 21c JDBC driver is compatible with the 19c server.
With JDK17 you can use either ojdbc8.jar or ojdbc10.jar. If you are planning to use the JDBC 4.3 APIs then you should use ojdbc10.jar.

Comment: There is table list in FAQ that says `JDBC 4.2 in ojdbc8.jar` and `JDBC 4.3 in ojdbc10.jar` for database 19.x under `What are the Oracle JDBC releases Vs JDBC specifications?` section. Which is I suppose it should be JDBC Version instead of Oracle Database Version same as `What are the Oracle JDBC releases Vs JDK versions?` section's table.

Comment: Java 8 is JDBC 4.2, Java 9+ is JDBC 4.3. I have updated your answer.